# Can't overwrite standard icons of jquery mobile search/filter field in android browser and emulator

Tags: jquery, search, mobile, icons, field

I wanted to replace jquery mobile's standard icons in the frameworks list view search field (when set: data-filter="true") with android specific icons. I found the responsible selector and overwrote jQM's path with my own. Everything looks fine on my desktop browsers (FF, Safari), but as soon as I start the emulator, there are no icons at all in the search field anymore.

Here is my class that works as I said on desktop browsers but not in the simulator or on device:

```
/* search icon (magnifier) at the beginning of search field */
.ui-icon-searchfield:after{
    background: url(../img/mdpi/2-action-search-dark.png) -5px -5px;
    height: 30px;
    width:30px;
    top: .8em;
    left: 0;

    border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}

/* delete icon (X) at the end of search field */
.ui-icon-delete{
    background: url(../img/mdpi/1-navigation-cancel-dark.png) -7px -7px;
    height: 18px;
    width:18px;
    border-radius: 0;
    opacity: .7;

    border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that the relative paths resolve correctly on the device / in the simulator? (Hint: "... as soon as I start the emulator, there are no icons at all in the search field anymore.")

Comment: Yes I'm certain that the path is correct, because I inserted the very same path in my header area and the icon is beeing displayed. Also if I take out the ":after" then I can see the icon in the field, but the field is not styled anymore ...

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue myself after some hours of trying so many things. The problem was that the image was there in the background the whole time, but totally misscaled!

There is a new CSS3 feature called background-size. This caused my background-image to be to big and not in the right proportion. So I set it to the size of my actual image (background-size: 32px 32px;) and voila, it's displayed in every browser!

```
/* search icon */
.ui-icon-searchfield:after{
    background-image: url(../img/mdpi/2-action-search-dark.png) 0 0;
    background-size: 32px 32px;
    height: 32px;
    width:32px;      
    margin-top: .15em;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}

/* delete icon */
.ui-icon-delete{
    background-image: url(../img/mdpi/1-navigation-cancel-dark.png);
    background-position: -7px -7px;
    background-size: 32px 32px;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 32px;
    width:32px;
    border-radius: 0;
    opacity: .7;

    border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
```